# How to center label between picture and edge

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, center

I am currently in the process of developing my website, where it'll be done entirely with CSS and JS, within a single page, entirely responsive.  I am currently stuck on an issue I am not sure there is a way around.

I have a div, that contains 1) a picture and 2) a label.  They are currently side by side.
When the mouse hovers over the div, the div extends to the right, but the picture stays the same size and location (left side of the div).
This makes the label appear (visibility set to true with JS) on the right side of the div.

My problem is I cannot figure out a way to center the label between the edge of the picture and the edge of the div it is contained within.

Here is some code:

index. html

```
<div class="menus1 " id = "menus1" style=" background-e:     url('../images/background1.jpg');">
<img class = "images" src = "../images/handshake.jpg" id="pen"/>
<label style=" margin-left:5%; color:black; " class="visibleLabel" id="aboutMeLabel"><b>About Me</b>    </label>
</div>
```

Where you see the "margin-left: 5%" is the closest thing I could get it to centering, it just isn't responsive.

Thank you :)

Comment: Could you plz provide a fiddle?

Comment: learn positions relative and absolute

Comment: Use `<div>` with CSS background instead of `<img>`. Then put label inside and set `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto`.

Comment: @Rav If I put the image at the back of the div, isnt it going to stretch with the div when the div extends?

Comment: are you using any psd for mapping it to html/css. i mean doing slicing work or writing your own html css

Answer (score 2):

First of all, take the `<style>` tags* out of your html  - its bad practice. Put all your style into your stylesheet. You can always add another class if needsbe.

- by this i mean this kind of thing

  style=" margin-left:5%; color:black; "

As for the centering, if you are looking to center the text within the label, just set your `label` css to `text-align:center;` - that would save a bit of bother.

Should you want to overlay the text on the image, then set the div background to the actual image? I see you have some kind of background there. You can always put a div within a div if thats your main background. And then include the label with the text-align-centered css within it.

Without a fiddle, or more code, it's difficult to know exactly what you're aiming for, but i hope this helps.

Rachel

Answer (score 2):

Create another css file for the style tag or Add the style into head for example

```
<style>
text-align:center;
margin-left:5%
color:black;
</style>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fodfka1L/)